# Running the Textarea Resizer jQuery plugin on a Textarea field generated from the X-Editable jQuery library

Tags: javascript, jquery, x-editable

Add the jQuery TextareaResizer `jquery.textarearesizer.js` library that StackOverflow uses to a textarea form field that us used by the jQuery edit in place library [X-Editable](https://github.com/vitalets/x-editable)

I have a simple working demo of the `Textarearesizer.js` plugin here http://codepen.io/jasondavis/pen/KpWybW which adds a Drag Hanlde to a textarea field and lets you click and drag to resise it.

I then try to add that same JavaScript code to make it work on a Textarea field generated from X-Editable here on this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/xBB5x/8558/

**X-Editable JavaScript:**

```
$('#description').editable({
    type: 'textarea',
    url: '/post',    
    pk: 1,    
    inputclass: 'task_description resizable',
    highlight: '#F1FFE7',
    mode: 'inline', // inline | popup
    placement: 'top',
    title: 'Enter Task Description',  
    validate: function(value) {
        if ($.trim(value) === '') {
            return 'Task Description is Required';
        }
    },
    params: function(params) {
        //Addition params in addition to the default: pk, name, value
        params.userId = 1;
        params.projectId = projectTaskModal.cache.projectId;
        params.taskId = projectTaskModal.cache.taskId;
        return params;
    },
    success: function(response, newValue) {
        if (!response.success) return response.msg;
    }
});
```

**Textarea Resizer JavaScript:**

```
/* jQuery textarea resizer plugin usage for Textarea */
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('textarea.resizable:not(.processed)').TextAreaResizer();
});
```

I don't get any error messages however the Textarea field does not run the resizer code.

On the JSFiddle demo http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/xBB5x/8558/ when you click teh Text, the Textarea is revealed.

I think it may have something to do with the Textarea not being visible when the `$('textarea.resizable:not(.processed)').TextAreaResizer();` code is ran since X-Editable does not show the Textarea until after you click on the text.

I also tried to do this:

```
$('#description').on('init', function(e, editable) {
    $('textarea.resizable:not(.processed)').TextAreaResizer();
});
```

which runs my callback code when the editable field is initialized

Answer (score 1):

I got it figured out.  MY Textarea generated by X-Editable was not being generated in the DOM until after my call to the TextareaReizer plugin.

The solution was to use this Event that is ran after the form textarea is shown in the DOM...

```
$('#description').on('shown', function(e, editable) {
    $('textarea.resizable:not(.processed)').TextAreaResizer();
});
```

Final solution demo working here http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/xBB5x/8559/